# Cannot call methods on table ? Table Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, table-valued-parameters, table-variable

I am trying to put outer apply on the table varible but I am getting error like below

Cannot call methods on table.

I  have Split function which split the string to certain length

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split(@String varchar(MAX), @SplitLength int) 
RETURNS @Result TABLE (Splited varchar(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = FLOOR((len(@String)/@SplitLength));

   While @Cnt!=0
    Begin
     SET @Cnt=@Cnt-1;
        While len(@String)>@SplitLength 
        Begin

         INSERT INTO @Result  VALUES (SUBSTRING(@String,1,@SplitLength))

         SET @String=SUBSTRING(@String,@SplitLength+1,len(@String)-@SplitLength) 

        End     

    End

RETURN
END
```

which I join with the  table variable which contain column which have string to be splited

```
    DECLARE @LeftSuper TABLE
(
KeyTerm VARCHAR(MAX),
Data VARCHAR(MAX) ,

)
```

Query is as following Which generates error (Cannot call methods on table )

```
 select KeyTerm ,D.Splited from @LeftSuper
 outer apply [Split](@LeftSuper.Data,300) as D
```

Note: code works fine with Real Table in db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce an alias for the table variable and use that in the expression:

```
select KeyTerm ,D.Splited from @LeftSuper ls
 outer apply [Split](ls.Data,300) as D
```

This is actually fairly common - because tables may appear more than once in a query, each time that `@LeftSuper` is encountered in the query, it's treated as a *new* reference to the table - not as the reference that has already been added - which the alias allows you to reference.